# Restore /etc/ configuration files from the default

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt

Is there a way to replace `/etc` configuration files from a package, overwriting my local changes? I've tried  `apt-get install --reinstall mypackage` but it doesn't update the files.

How can I do this?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12748/4671

Answer (score 40, accepted):

A [related serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/82801/linux-how-to-restore-config-file-using-apt-get-aptitude) describes how to restore package conffiles if you've removed them, and requires that you track down the actual `.deb` file.

All you need to do:

- Find the list of conffiles provided by the package:

  ```
  dpkg --status <package>
  ```

  (look under the `Conffiles:` section).
- Remove those conffiles yourself.
- Reinstall the package.  If you've found the `.deb` file,

  ```
  dpkg -i --force-confmiss <package_deb>.deb
  ```

  Alternatively, passing the `dpkg` option via `apt` should work:

  ```
  apt-get install --reinstall -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" <package>
  ```

Comment: Nice, thanks. What if you don't know in particular which package provides a file?

Comment: `dpkg -S /file/to/search` give you the package name

Answer (score 6):

Besides `remove` apt-get also offers the `purge` command which cleans out your config customizations, which can then be followed by an `apt-get install`

Comment: `purge` certainly works for many packages but not the essential ones that you can't remove without seriously breaking things.

Answer (score 2):

```
apt-get install -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confnew" packagename
```

Comment: Didn't work for me on raspberry pi os at least

Comment: Newer ones need `DPKG_FORCE=confmiss apt-get install --reinstall packagename` .