# How to reinstall configuration file

Tags: apt, package-management

How do you revert or reinstall a configuration file in Debian/Ubuntu?

I accidentally overwrote the file `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`. Running `dpkg -S /etc/bluetooth/main.conf` shows that the package `bluez` provides it, but when I run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bluez`, it doesn't get reinstalled.

Comment: Related (possibly dupe) https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12748/4671

Comment: Lets turn this duplicate arround, this question deals with the more generic problem and has an answer that goes to the point solving the problem stated in the title.

Answer (score 8):

## Solution 1

Run the following command, replacing package-name with the name of the package:

```
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" install --reinstall package-name
```

## Solution 2

If you have `.deb` package then go to that directory where package is exist and run,

```
dpkg -i --force-confmiss package-name.deb
```

Answer (score 7):

You should `mv` the file out of the way:

```
mv /etc/bluetooth/main.conf /etc/bluetooth/main.conf.old
apt-get -o DPkg::options::=--force-confmiss --reinstall install bluez
```

I don't know if you can get `apt` to overwrite an existing config file, that's why you should move it out of the way first.