# What's the best way to restore a deleted file from a package in debian?

Tags: debian, apt

/etc/sudoers had been deleted, and I wanted to restore the default file from the package. I tried:

`apt-get install sudo
apt-get install --reinstall sudo
apt-get remove sudo && apt-get install sudo`

None of which worked but all of which warned about /etc/sudoers not existing.

In the end I did `apt download sudo && ar xv sudo && tar xf data.tar.xz ./etc/sudoers` and just copied that file to /etc/sudoers, but was there a more straightforward way to restore the file?

Comment: Dupe https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277193/how-to-reinstall-configuration-file and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12597/missing-init-d-apache2-file and I don't know why autosuggest didn't find at least the former.

Comment: What error message did you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract the contents of a `.deb` package as follows:

```
dpkg-deb --extract sudo_1.8.26-2_amd64.deb /tmp/sudo
```

This extracts the contents of the `.deb` into `/tmp/sudo/`. Now you can copy `/tmp/sudo/etc/sudoers`.

Alternatively you could run `dpkg -i --force-confmiss sudo_1.8.26-2_amd64.deb`. This forces reinstalling missing conffiles.